# How to set up Python packages

Tags: python, module, package

I want this structure:

Zimp/controller/game_play -->How do I: import Zimp/model/game_play module in the easiest way?
Zimp/model/game_play

I made a folder called controller and a folder called model. Within those folders I put an empty `__init__.py` file (don't know why that would do anything). I didn't make a model.py file or a controller.py file. It didn't work. I just made a model.py and a controller.py that are empty except for the main block that automatically appears when creating a new module. No difference.

In controller/game_play.py I tried: `from ..model import game_play_model`

It says value error: attempted relative import in non-package

Is the idea not to actually put them in separate directories? What is the norm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to execute a subpackage module directly, see answers to the question [*Attempted relative import in non-package even with __init__.py*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py).

First I think you need to set up your directory file structure like this:

```
Zimp/                       top-level package
    __init__.py                 package initalization
    controller/                     subpackage
        __init__.py                     subpackage initalization
        game_play.py                    subpackage module
    model/                          subpackage
        __init__.py                     subpackage initalization
        game_play_model.py              subpackage module
```

The `__init__.py` files can all be empty as they just indicate that the directory is a [sub]package.
For illustrative purposes let's say the`game_play_model.py`file contained:

```
print 'hello from game_play_model.py'
```

and the`game_play.py`file contains the following to detect when it was being executed directly and adds the name of the parent of its folder — `Zimp` — to the Python search path — thus allowing you to then directly import other things from the package when it's run that way.

```
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    import sys, os.path as path
    # append parent of the directory the current file is in
    sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(__file__)))

import model.game_play_model

print 'hello from game_play.py'
```

And you executed it directly with something like`python game_play.py`it would output:

```
hello from game_play_model.py
hello from game_play.py
```

Comment: Thanks I have that file structure and code but it still won't recognise a module named model.game_play_model. My zimp folder also has a _pycache__ folder in it if that makes a difference. I copeied your if statement word for word. Not sure I was meant to.

Comment: The `if` statement and `sys.path.append()` call have to appear before the `import` statement.

Comment: Note you can also use `sys.path.append(path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '..')))` which some feel is clearer about what's being done.

Comment: This would be even better IMHO: `sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(__file__)))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Zimp.model import game_play
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I got "no module named Zimp.model". I only made Zimp as a folder..So I should create a new module named zimp. And inside it what should I write? Thank you!!

Comment: I think it might be better if you read up on how Python modules work: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Thanks, I have already read that. It doesn't say how to create the structure. Only how to work with it once it is done.

Comment: Are you sure? ;) http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages. In short, packages are just (sub) directories. Just make sure you have a `__init__.py` file inside the directory. Otherwise it's not recognised as a package/module. Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, but I do have that file in the directories :(